# Aggregating totals using recursion - works one parent-child level only

Tags: c#, recursion, sum

I have a treeview control with a list of objects attached to each node. When a node is selected I want to know the total count of objects for the selected node and all its children.

The recursive function traverses the tree as expected but I am not aggregating the sums correctly.  It only adds values from the current node and the children one level down.

I am sure the last line in my code is incorrect (return n.Maps.Count), but I don't know how to aggregate the values if the hierarchy is deeper than one level.

Appreciate any help.  Regards Chris

```
private void CallingFunction()
{
    .... <some unrelated code> ...

    foreach (GeoSchemeTreeNode n in node.Nodes)
    {
        xx += AddTotal(n);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"total={xx});
}

private int AddTotal(GeoSchemeTreeNode n)
{
    foreach (GeoSchemeTreeNode i in n.Nodes)
    {
        AddTotal(i);
    }

    return n.Maps.Count;
}
```

Comment: You need to sum up the results of the recursive `AddTotal` calls and add that sum in the `return` statement.

Comment: To save nested values create optional parameter in your AddTotal which will store previous level values. For example: `AddTotal(GeoSchemeTreeNode n, int value = 0)`

and just parse that in your foreach and return `value + n.Maps.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that you aren't actually storing and totalling the product of the recursions.

The fixed method should look something like this:

```cs
private int AddTotal(GeoSchemeTreeNode n)
{
    int total = n.Maps.Count;

    foreach (GeoSchemeTreeNode i in n.Nodes)
    {
        total += AddTotal(i);
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response Anthony - works a charm!